# difference between using i18n library and using loacle directly fron JSON in vue.js

Tags: angular, reactjs, vue.js, internationalization

I wanted to use Chinese in my vue app so I just loaded whole JSON text in vuex and used text loaded in store, without using i18n library.

Please tell me is there any side effect of this approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should keep in mind things like:

- pluralization
- date formatting
- number formatting
- currency formatting
- fallback language

If you don't use a library like [this](http://kazupon.github.io/vue-i18n/introduction.html) one, you'll have to build the logic handling these things on your own (and expand that logic if you add more languages later).

Another thing is sharing translation files between your backend, and the Vue app. If you're using a localization library, there can be an option to reuse translation strings on the server and the client side. [Here](https://github.com/martinlindhe/laravel-vue-i18n-generator) you can check such library for Laravel PHP.